# Firefox can't access internet in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.04, internet-connection

I installed Ubuntu 10.04. Firefox will not access the internet. It works fine in 10.04.

This happens every time Firefox opens. Do I have to update the kernel, is there another way?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Firefox can't access the internet and it "works fine in 10.04"? What do you mean by that? Do other services have access to the internet in your Ubuntu installation? Have you checked whether you modified Firefox's default settings?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to update the Linux kernel.

You have to identify the cause of the problem, typically this involves looking for error messages and describing the exact symptoms.

There are diagnostic tools you can use in a command-prompt window. For example.

```
  sudo ifconfig
  netstat -nr
  host www.google.com
  ping www.google.com
  traceroute www.google.com
  wget www.google.com
```

You may need to install traceroute using

```
  sudo apt-get install traceroute
```

---

Here's relevant extractts of what those commands produce on a working system

```
$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:ff:19:60:1a:00
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0

$ host www.google.com
www.google.com is an alias for www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.66.99
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.66.105
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.66.104
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.66.106
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.66.103
www.l.google.com has address 173.194.66.147

$ ping -c 5 www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (173.194.66.147) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4000ms
```

Oops - OK Google block ping, that's OK

```
$ wget www.google.com
--2012-05-18 15:59:51--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 173.194.66.105, 173.194.66.104, 173.194.66.106, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|173.194.66.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

    [ <=>                                   ] 12,013      --.-K/s   in 0.02s

2012-05-18 15:59:52 (587 KB/s) - `index.html' saved [12013]
```

Comment: wow, it's ok. I will try  it now, thank's guys